Introspective timestamp fields with Mongoose and NestJS
End Goal: Find an easy way to have timestamps (createdAt and updatedAt) appended to Mongoose Schemas (using NestJS decorators) and have them be introspective in Apollo sandbox without having to specify the fields on every Schema. I want other developers to be able to specify a new class that we would use as a collection, and have these fields added, be selectable through code, and be introspective through the Sandbox for ease of development. We might add other fields in the future.
Issue I'm having: I can add { timestamps: true } to an @Schema() that I create (which automatically adds them to the database), but without adding the fields directly as @Prop()s, when I try to reference the fields in Apollo Sandbox, I get the error "Cannot query field "createdAt|updatedAt" on type "Company".
I have tried Creating a base class with { timestamps: true } and adding the two fields createdAt and updatedAt there as Props and having another class extend it. This lets me see those fields in Typescript, but doesn't resolve in introspection.
Here is the full schema.
import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, HydratedDocument, Model, Types } from 'mongoose';

import { collationEn } from '@api/mongoose/mongoose.constants';


@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Base {
  @Prop()
  @Field(() => Date, { description: 'Company created date' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Prop()
  @Field(() => Date, { description: 'Company updated date' })
  updatedAt: Date;
}

@Schema({ collection: 'company' })
@ObjectType()
export class Company extends Base {
  @Field(() => String, { description: 'Company ID' })
  _id: Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ index: { unique: true, collation: collationEn } })
  @Field(() => String, { description: 'Company name' })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ default: null })
  @Field(() => String, { description: 'Company address', nullable: true })
  address?: string;

  @Prop({ default: null })
  @Field(() => String, { description: 'Company website URL', nullable: true })
  website?: string;
}

export type BaseDocument = Base & Document; // Added this after seeing a few other posts that did a similar thing, not sure if this is even needed.
export type CompanyModel = Model<Company>;
export type CompanyDocument = HydratedDocument<Company>;

export const CompanyToken = 'Company';
const BaseSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Base);
export const CompanySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Company).add(BaseSchema);

```



I was able to coerce Copilot into giving me a suitable answer.
